# Elasticsearch - "error": "no handler found for uri

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I'm new to Elasticsearch. Everything seems to be wroking fine but when I run the json code below. It gives the error: "error": "no handler found for uri [/vehicles/car/01?pretty=&pretty=true] and method [PUT]"

```
PUT /vehicles/car/01?pretty
{
  "make": "Lexus",
  "color": "Black",
  "HP": 300
}
```

I've extracted Elasticsearch & kebana in the Downloads folder. Installed Brew & JAVA JDK via terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using very old documentation because [mapping types have been removed in 8.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html), so the `car` URI part in your URL is what is causing the issue. Just use `_doc` instead of `car` and you'll be fine.

```
           change this
              ||||
              vvvv
PUT /vehicles/_doc/01?pretty
{
  "make": "Lexus",
  "color": "Black",
  "HP": 300
}
```

Comment: Cool, glad it helped!